# Difference between the words for "feeling"

Tags: word-choice, words

I have seen and been taught many words meaning "feeling", but what is the difference between the words, and where are they used?

I have done a bit of research myself and have come up with these meanings. Are they correct? Could someone please give a more detailed explanation?

- 具合 - health related
- 気分 - mood
- 気持ち - inner/emotional feeling
- 感じ - outside/perceived feeling
- 感覚 - ?
- 感情 - ?
- 意識 - ?
- 情 - ?
- 情意 - ?
- 心持ち - ?

Are there any others I should know about?

Comment: Where are you seeing まま as feeling?

Comment: 「感覚{かんかく}」 might be one.　「意識」another.

Comment: @ssb I saw it while playing through 二ノ国. It was part of a non-repeatable sidequest so I can't get you an exact quote :/

Comment: Ahh well it's probable that you either misinterpreted that one or there's a new word for feeling that I've never heard of..

Comment: 感情 is used for emotions eg 感情的＝emotional, 感情を込めて謝りました＝He apologized with real feeling. 感覚 is used for sense eg 金銭感覚= sense for the value of money.

Comment: I'm a bit surprised nobody has chimed in on this with some more detailed information. Maybe a bounty is in order?

Comment: You may want to include `[体調]{たい・ちょう}`.  It technically means "physical/bodily condition", but you hear it often in `体調がいい・悪い` to mean "I feel good/bad".  Basically, it's the same as `体の具合`.

Comment: Also missing: 触れる、触る

Comment: ...and 感触.  This could get out of hand.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

- 具合【ぐあい】 - Health / condition. It's worth noting that this doesn't apply exclusively to people, though!

  - 「エンジンの具合を調【しら】べる」 ("Check the condition of the engine.")
  - 「具合が悪【わる】いので休【やす】む」 ("I'm not feeling to good today so I'm gonna rest.")
- 気分【きぶん】 - Mood.

  - 「仕事【しごと】をする気分になれない」 ("I can't get into the mood to do work.")
  - 「今日【きょう】は気分がのらない」 ("I'm not in the mood today.")
  - Can also be somewhat synonymous with 雰囲気【ふんいき】. 「音楽【おんがく】が会場【かいじょう】の気分を盛【も】り上【あ】げる」 ("Music really ups the mood of the meeting area.")
- 気持【きも】ち - Feeling about something. The first definition on Kotobank says "The emotion / what you feel in your heart upon encountering something / an event taking place." Almost sort of like an opinion, but more emotional than that? Kind of difficult to define, I guess...

  - 「気持ちが変【か】わる」 ("[Subject's] feelings are changing.")
  - 「彼【かれ】の気持ちが理解【りかい】できない」 ("I can't understand the way he feels [about a particular thing happening].")
- 感【かん】じ - Sensation or impression. Can be used in both the physical and emotional senses.

  - 「指先【ゆびさき】の感じがなくなる」 ("Lose the feeling in the tip of one's finger.")
  - 「感じのいい人【ひと】」 ("A person who seems good [/ who makes a good impression].")
  - 「春【はる】らしい感じの日【ひ】ざし」 ("Sunshine that makes it seem like a Spring day.")
- 感覚【かんかく】 - Sense. Again, it can be used in both the physical and the more metaphorical.

  - 「寒【さむ】さで指の感覚がなくなる」 ("So cold one loses the sensation in one's finger.")
  - 「新【しん】感覚のデザイン」 ("A design made with a new sense [of style].")
- 感情【かんじょう】 - Pure emotions. Pleasure, displeasure, like, hate, fear, anger, etc.

  - 「国民【こくみん】感情を刺激【しげき】する」 ("Stir up the emotions of the nation's people.")
- 意識【いしき】 - Consciousness / be conscious of.

  - 「意識を取【と】り戻【もど】す」 ("Return to consciousness.")
  - 「彼女【かのじょ】の存在【そんざい】を意識する」 ("To be aware of her existence.")
- 情【じょう】 - Emotion. A pretty broad word; kind of difficult to concisely define. Emotions, feelings, literal, more metaphysical... Lots of possibilities.

  - 「憂国【ゆうこく】の情」 ("A feeling of love for one's country.")
  - 「情の深【ふか】い人」 ("An emotional person.")
  - In certain contexts it can refer to romantic feelings specifically. 「夫婦【ふうふ】の情」 ("A couple's love.")
- 情意【じょうい】 - Feeling in one's heart. Pretty much synonymous with 気持ち, according to my dictionary.

  - 「情意[相通]{あいつう}じる」 ("Share one's feelings.")
- 心持【こころも】ち - One's emotional state.

  - 「心持ちのよい人」 - ("A calm [/ cool] person.")
  - *Also* can be synonymous with 気持ち. 「心持ちが悪【わる】い」 ("[Something that] feels bad.")

**EDIT:** Comments from istrasci and Kaji have presented more words, and I felt it would be good to include them!

- 体調【たいちょう】 - The condition of one's body (more generally, "health").

  - 「体調を整【ととの】える」 ("Improve one's health.")
  - 「体調が良【よ】い」 ("In good health." alternatively, per istrasci, "I feel good.")
- 触【ふ】れる - To touch. Many nuanced definitions are available for this word, so I'll just focus on the ones that are more related to our discussion here.

  - One meaning is "to take on an emotion (usually negative?)":「怒【いか】りに触れる」 ("To anger [/ offend / upset] somebody.")
  - Another is more straight-forward: 「心【こころ】に触れる話【はなし】」 ("A talk [/ word / conversation] that touches the heart.")
- 触【さわ】る - Also to touch, but slightly different. The only emotional definition here is negative: being angry about something.

  - 「神経【しんけい】に触る」 ("To get on one's nerves.")
  - 「癇【かん】に障【さわ】る」 ("To get on one's nerves." This isn't a typo, by the way; as far as I can tell, this is the only correct way to write this particular phrase. The meaning is very similar, though, and I felt it was relevant enough to include.)

All definitions and example sentences come from [Kotobank](http://kotobank.jp/)! I can't think of any more related words, so I suppose this will do. :) If anyone has any corrections or clarifications (I'm not *super* confident on a couple of the translations), please do bring them up in the comments!

Comment: [Eijiro](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=feeling) has a few more.

Comment: I feel like 気味 and [気]{け} also fit the bill ^^

Comment: If you get a chance, could you please add 心地?