# Another four words meaning "feeling", what are their differences?

Tags: word-choice, words, nuances

I came across a lot of Japanese words meaning "feeling" (as can be seen in Jisho.org):

- 感情{かんじょう} (*kanjou*)
- 気持ち{きもち} (*kimochi*)
- 感覚{かんかく} (*kankaku*)
- 感じ{かんじ} (*kanji*)
- 心持ち{こころもち} (*kokoromochi*)
- 心地{ここち} (*kokochi*)
- 感触{かんしょく} (*kanshoku*)
- 情感{じょうかん} (*joukan*)
- 情緒{じょうちょ} (*joucho*)

Most are already covered in [this question from 2014](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/15472/), but unfortunately, not all of them. Therefore, my question here is supposed to be a continuation of that question, to fill the gaps of the missing words, and by no means a duplicate.

The words that weren't addressed in the linked question are the last four:

- 心地{ここち} (*kokochi*)
- 感触{かんしょく} (*kanshoku*)
- 情感{じょうかん} (*joukan*)
- 情緒{じょうちょ} (*joucho*)

What are the differences in usage among them all? And can all of them be used in casual speech?

Answer (score 2):

When all’s said and done, you could only grasp their difference in meaning by using these nouns in commonly used, practical phrases:

生きた**心地**がしなかった : I ***felt like*** my heart was in my mouth (as the chopper was caught in a thunderstorm).

ひんやりとした**感触**です: (something) ***feels*** cool ***to the touch***

**情感**豊かにピアノで曲を演奏する: play a piano piece in a way that ***moves*** people's  ***hearts***

**情緒**不安定: the state of being ***emotionally*** unstable